# append string to string array if not array yet

Tags: javascript

I want to create a array of strings by appending, but it matters if the origin is an array or yet a string.
Therefore I need to convert a string like "abc" to a string array.

if I use

```
Array.from()
```

it makes me something like this ["a","b","c"]
but I want to have ["abc"];

Is there a easy way that takes an input like
"abc"
and at the same time ["a","abc"]
I so that I can append later one one more string with push for example?

some constraints:
I cannot create

```
let a = [];
```

because it is coming from extern.
And sure, I can add some code to check what is its, but I search for a simple mechanism.

I think i need something like
arr1.flat();

Comment: What is the structure of your original input?

Comment: `let a = []; a.push("abc");` is that what you want?

Comment: i don't see why you don't just use [string] instead of Array.from()

Comment: if you want to have controle over all entries you could do something like: `array.reduce((array, entry) => [(array[0] ?? '')  + entry], '');`

Comment: As an alternative if you know for sure the array can only contain strings you could do `[array.toString().replaceAll(',', '')]`.

Comment: Lastly with simply concats at the same level you could do `[array.join('')]`. Good luck

Comment: @NilsSchwebel beause if input is already an array i have it doulbed. and i want to avoid the checking logic

Comment: @Boellner I don't think there's a straightforward way to avoid the 'checking logic'. Unless you're specifically optimizing for performance it's usually best to use the simplest solution, even at a tiny performance cost. Let me know if I can improve my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this does what you want:

```js
function strArr(base,s){
 return !Array.isArray(base)?[base,s]:[...base,s];
}

let a="abc", arr=["one","two"];

console.log(strArr(a,"b"));
console.log(strArr(arr,"three"));
```

I changed my answer slightly. Now the input array `base` will not be changed anymore by the function.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your question correctly, you want to either append the source to an existing array if it's a string or concatenate the source if it's already an array?

Have you tried `typeof`? See the [MDN typeof docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

```
if (typeof origin === 'string') {
   mylist.push(origin)
} else {
   mylist = mylist.concat(origin)
}
```

EDIT:
As per NiceBooks comment:

```
let str = new String('Hello, world')
typeof str // 'object'
```

([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#using_new_operator))

Therefore, as they suggested the following might be better:

```
if (Array.isArray(origin)) {
   mylist = mylist.concat(origin) // there are more cleaner ways, for starters this should be fine
} else {
   mylist.push(origin)
}
```

Comment: Using `typeof` isn't a 100% solution to check if a variable is a String (`typeof` of strings created through the String constructor is `object`). On the other hand `Array.isArray(origin)` is the best way to check if a variable is an Array.

Comment: @NiceBooks Interesting, I didn't know that. I'll look into it and add it to my answer. Thanks.